# Using jquery to run code when django document is ready

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, django, events

I am building a django admin site and am using javascript and jquery (2.0.3) to add some extra functionality to the forms.

I am importing the scripts into my page like this:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/admin/js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/admin/js/jquery.init.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/project/js/project.js"></script>
    </head>
    <!-- ... -->
</html>
```

At first I placed the following code at the end of `project.js`:

```js
function tryCustomiseForm() {
    // ...
}

$(document).ready(tryCustomiseForm);
```

Unfortunately this results in an `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function` exception on the last line.

I then tried the alternative syntaxes of [`ready()`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) without any more luck.

Lastly I explored the `change_form.html` template and found this inline javascript:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function($) {
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('form#{{ opts.model_name }}_form :input:visible:enabled:first').focus()
        });
    })(django.jQuery);
</script>
```

I was able to modify it to suit my needs and now my `project.js` ends with:

```js
(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        tryCustomiseForm();
    });
})(django.jQuery);
```

While this results in the correct behaviour *I don't understand it*.

This leads to my question: Why did my first approach fail? And what is the second approach doing?

Comment: I think the django framework uses the dollar `$` sign for something else rather then jQuery. Therefore you need to create a container around your jQuery functions where you assign the jQuery to the dollar sign only for the code inside the container

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's hard to tell from the code you've posted, but it looks like the `$` variable is not assigned to jQuery in your template; hence the `$()` construct threw the `undefined function` error.

The reason the latter works is because it puts a closure around your DOMReady handler, which passes in `django.jQuery`, which I assume to be the `noConflict` jQuery assigned variable from your template, and assigns it to the `$` within the scope of that:

```
(function($) { // < start of closure
    // within this block, $ = django.jQuery
    $(document).ready(function() {
        tryCustomiseForm();
    });
})(django.jQuery); // passes django.jQuery as parameter to closure block
```

Comment: It looks like this is correct as the following works `django.jQuery(document).ready(tryCustomiseForm);`  Thanks for the help.

Comment: @KellyThomas , I find the [jQuery noconflict docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/) helpful for explaining this.

Answer (score 2):

The Django docs [explain this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/admin/#jquery): jQuery is namespaced, so you can use `django.jQuery` to refer to it within admin templated.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$(document).ready(function(){

 tryCustomiseForm();

}); 

function tryCustomiseForm() {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: This is logically exactly the same as what the OP first tried, which did not work.

Comment: It's not exactly the same as the `tryCustomiseForm()` function is called within another, anonymous function.